# Can't style with SASS/SCSS in React properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, sass

Take this SCSS stylesheet:

```
@import "../vars";

img.userIcon {
  &.regular {
    max-width: 64px;
    max-height: 64px;
  }
  &.small {
    max-width: 32px;
    max-height: 32px;
  }
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid $bg-light;
}
```

How on earth do I get my page to recognise the `.regular` or `.small`?

This my `UserIcon.tsx` that applies this styling:

```
import styles from "../styles/components/UserIcon.module.scss";

type Props = {
    src: string,
    variant?: "regular" | "small"
}
export default function UserIcon({ src, variant = "regular" }: Props) {
    return <img className={`${styles.userIcon} ${variant} mb-2`} src={src} />
}
```

Now, this obviously won't work because somewhere along the lines, the class names are all jumbled up and look like this:

```
<img class="UserIcon_userIcon__1jFAP regular mb-2">
```

Which is odd, because it doesn't ever do this to the boostrap scss files that I have imported.

So I need to know either:

- How to remove the class name renaming.
- How to implement `.regular` and `.small` properly, such that it uses the jumbled up name.

Comment: This is called "CSS Modules" and they are a very very good thing. You want those "jumbled up" class names, believe it or not. The classnames become globally unique strings, allowing you to have the same class names in different files that do not clash with each other. The downside is having to translate all the classnames through an imported css object. But it's worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass `variant` as key argument to your styles object:

```
return <img className={`${styles.userIcon} ${styles[variant]} mb-2`} src={src} />
```

Comment: This works! But is there any way I can disable the renaming?

Comment: I believe one of the reasons to use CSS module is to generate unique class names to avoid name collision. https://medium.com/@pioul/modular-css-with-react-61638ae9ea3e.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like that.

```css
@import "../vars";

img.userIcon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid $bg-light;
}
img.regular {
    max-width: 64px;
    max-height: 64px;
  }
img.small {
    max-width: 32px;
    max-height: 32px;
  }
```

```js
import styles from "../styles/components/UserIcon.module.scss";

type Props = {
    src: string,
    variant?: "regular" | "small"
}
export default function UserIcon({ src, variant = "regular" }: Props) {
    return <img className={`${styles.userIcon} ${styles[variant]} mb-2`} src={src} />
}
```

Tell me if it solved your problem

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem, because now it won't apply any of the styling at all, not even the border radius, as if it can't find the class at all.

Comment: hmm that is very strange

Comment: Can you try just `<img className="userIcon" src={src} />` plaese

Comment: Yes, I did. Something is changing the names of my classes. This is how they look when running the page: https://i.imgur.com/S8MsEz4.png

Comment: I need to now what are you using to configure scss/sass

Comment: I have no idea. It's using webpack but there's no config in my project, and I'm using Next which I guess is handling that.

Comment: Oh ok so you are using CSS modules with nextjs.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try the solution and tell me if it works?